# Add macro to insert textbox

Tags: excel

Is there any possibility to add a textbox via a macro? So I click the Link and it adds a textbox... What I did before is to set the default look of a textbox. So it always look how I want when I add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to create a working button now... I used this code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationVertical, 361.5, 59.25, 420, _
    90.75).Select
Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = _
    "Here you have your textbox"
Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 26).ParagraphFormat. _
    FirstLineIndent = 0
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I recorded a Macro for that... It may not be the best solution, but it does the task you asked for.

```
Sub AddTextbox()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 361.5, 59.25, 420, _
    90.75).Select
Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = _
    "Here you have your textbox"
Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 26).ParagraphFormat. _
    FirstLineIndent = 0
With Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 26).Font
    .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
    .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
    .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
    .Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorDark1
    .Fill.ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
    .Fill.ForeColor.Brightness = 0
    .Fill.Transparency = 0
    .Fill.Solid
    .Size = 11
    .Name = "+mn-lt"
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks alot for that. Thats probably a stupid question, but where do I have to add this code? I have no administrator rights on the computer I am working on.

Comment: I figured it out now, where to add this. Now i have a button, but when I click on it, nothing happens. Do I probably have to add a position where to add the textbox?

Comment: you have to link the macro to the button you created

Comment: sorry, but how do I do that? On the Command Button there's the formula =EINBETTEN("Forms.CommandButton.1";"")

Comment: I'm not sure wether you have the developer tab activated or not... but that will help! check this link for that:

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Show-the-Developer-tab-e1192344-5e56-4d45-931b-e5fd9bea2d45

and then to asign a macro to the button check this one...

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-a-button-and-assign-a-macro-to-it-in-a-worksheet-d58edd7d-cb04-4964-bead-9c72c843a283

Comment: Yes i have the developer tab activated. Then i did " Insert > Command Button > Show Code > and then i inserted the code.

Comment: Okay I see!
Insert a form control button and it will automatically suggest you to link a macro to the button click. I think this will answer your question! :D

Comment: Yup, its working now :D I posted an answer. Do you probably know how to set the size and position of the box?

Comment: ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationVertical, 361.5, 59.25, 420, _
    90.75).Select
change the values on that row, try until it is ok for you

Comment: Tho i suggest you to use the macro recorder for the next time... it took me only 1 minute to make that macro, and it will fit perfectly for your use!